# How to set access token globally in angularjs

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api, google-api-js-client

How to set access token globally in angular so that I don't have to set it each time google api is called?so far I have found:

```
       gapi.auth.setToken({
        access_token:myaccesstoken
        });
```

Comment: You can save it in browser storage(`localstorage` and `sessionstorage`) if its okay, or you can also save the variable in `$rootScope` and access it across child `$scope`s. Best is to have a factory, and handle the access token their. And pass it to other directives/controllers when required.

Comment: Thank you very much @sam